# Why LLVM is not suitable to design a static analyzer?

Tags: static-analysis

I'm reading a paper, and there is this paragraph about LLVM:

> ''it heavily relies on the static single assignment form
>   (SSA) which cannot be readily used to design an abstract interpreter.
>   The $\phi$-nodes need to be eliminated and other inadequate constructs need
>   to be simplified using various LLVM transformation passes"

I understand the $\phi$-nodes need to be unrolled, but what are some examples of inadequate constructs in LLVM that make it unsuitable to design a static analyzer based on abstract interpretation?

Comment: Xcode uses a static analyser based on LLVM

Comment: @gnasher729 the paper I'm reading also used LLVM, but it transforms LLVM into its own IR.

Comment: Since there is a static analyser based on LLVM (and it is bloody good), the assertion that LLVM is unsuitable is clearly false. So any problem should be elsewhere.

Comment: @gnasher729: by "suitable", I mean why it is not possible to implement the algorithm directly on top of it, without transformation to another language.